# Searching Table View with Subtitles in Cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a table view and can search for the titles.  I'm wanting to add subtitles to the cells, which I know how to do, but I'd like to be able to search by info in the subtitles as wells as titles.  The index of each item in the subtitles array, corresponds to the object at the same index in the title array.  So, one problem I have is, when I search and the table view auto updates according to the search text, I need to have the correct subtitle show with it.  The same thing would need to be done if I search for text that is in the subtitle.  It would need to show the correct title for the subtitle. Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
#import "List.h"
#import "RSFM.h"
#import "DTCustomColoredAccessory.h"

@interface List ()

@end

@implementation List
{
    NSMutableArray *title;
    NSMutableArray *subtitle;
    NSMutableArray *displayItems;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    title = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Cates Farm", @"Broadbent B & B Foods", @"Cayce's Pumpkin Patch", @"Metcalfe Landscaping", @"Brumfield Farm Market", @"Dogwood Valley Farm", @"Country Fresh Meats & Farmers Market", @"Jim David Meats", @"Trunnell's Farm Market", @"Lovell's Orchard & Farm Market", @"Zook's Produce", @"The Country Barn", @"Poore's Nursery & Farms", @"Just Piddlin Farm", @"Chaney's Dairy Barn & Restaurant", @"Jackson's Orchard & Nursery, Inc.", @"Mammoth Cave Transplants", @"Habegger's Amish Market", @"Kenny's Farmhouse Cheese", @"Dennison's Roadside Market", @"Roberts Family Farm", @"Wooden Farm", @"Lee's Garden Center, Florist & Gift Shop", @"Hinton's Orchard & Farm Market", @"Serenity Farm Alpacas", @"Burton's Nursery & Garden Center", @"Davis Family Farms", @"Heavenly Haven Farm", @"French Valley Farms", @"Cravens Greenhouse", @"Haney's Appledale Farm", @"Hettmansperger's Greenhouse", @"D & F Farms", @"Double Hart Farm", @"Owens Garden Center", @"Hail's Farm", @"Sinking Valley Vineyard & Winery, Inc.", @"Todd's Greenhouse & Florist, LLC", @"McQuerry's Family Farm-Herbs-N-Heirlooms", @"Berea College Farm & Gardens", @"Acres of Land Winery & Restaurant", @"Baldwin Farms", @"Wonder of Life Farm", @"Chateau du Vieux Corbeau Winery/Old Crow Farm Winery", @"Devine's Farm & Corn Maze", @"Williams Country Market", @"Serano Alpacas & Yarns", @"St. Catharine Farm", @"Capture Your Heart Alpacas", @"Ridgeview Greenhouse & Nursery", @"Country Corner Greenhouse & Nursery, Inc", @"Sunny Acres Farm", @"Morrison's Greenhouses", @"George Gagel Farm Market, LLC", @"Thieneman's Herbs & Perennials", @"Tower View Farm & Nursery", @"Gallrein Farms", @"Sweet Home Spun in the Low Dutch Meetinghouse", @"Mulberry Orchard, LLC", @"Gregory Farms", @"Sherwood Acres Beef", @"Bray Orchard & Roadside Market", @"Callis Orchards", @"Bray Fruit", @"Wilson's Nursery", @"Triple J Farm", @"Ayres Family Orchard", @"Michels Family Farm", @"Amerson Farm", @"Bi-Water Farm & Greenhouse", @"Alpine Hills Dairy Tour/Country Pumpkins", @"Blue Ribbon Market", @"Eagle Bend Alpacas Fiber & Gift Shoppe", @"Redman's Farm",@"The Greenhouse in Gertrude", @"Croppers Greenhouse & Nursery", @"McLean's Aerofresh Fruit", @"Julie's Pumpkins", @"Reed Valley Orchard", @"Evans Orchard & Cider Mill", @"Antioch Daylily Garden", @"Golden Apple Fruit Market", @"Boyd Orchards", @"Serenity Hill Fiber & Living History Farm", @"Beech Springs Farm Market", @"Yuletide Tree Farm & Nursery", @"Townsend's Sorghum Mill and Farm Market", @"Bramble Ridge Orchard", @"Country Garden Greenhouse", @"Golden Apple Fruit Market", @"Black Barn Produce, LLC", @"Imel's Greenhouse", @"Feathered Wing Farm Market", @"Hutton-Loyd Tree Farm", @"Halcomb's Knob, LLC", @"Happy Hollow Farms", @"Reid's Orchard", @"McKinney Farm", @"Crawford Farms", @"Brian T. Guffey Livestock & Produce", @"MeadowBrook Orchards & Farm", @"Rising Sons Home Farm Winery", @"VanMeter Family Farm", nil];

    subtitle = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Hwy 425 Henderson, KY 42420", @"257 Mary Blue Road Kuttawa, KY 42055", @"153 Farmersville Road Princeton, KY 42445", @"410 Princeton Road Madisonville, KY 42431", @"3320 Nebo Road Madisonville, KY 42431", @"4551 State Route 109N Clay, KY 42404", @"9355 US Hwy 60 W Sturgis, KY 42459",@"350 T. Frank Wathen Rd. Uniontown, KY 42461", @"9255 Hwy 431 Utica, KY 42376", @"22850 Coal Creek Road Hopkinsville, KY 42240", @"Intersection of KY107 & KY117 Herndon, KY   42240", @"112 Britmart Road Elkton, KY 42220", @"5486 Morgantown Road   Russellville, KY 42276", @"10830 S. Morgantown Rd.  Woodburn, KY 42170", @"9191 Nashville Road, Bowling Green, KY 42101", @"1280 Slim Island Road   Bowling Green, KY 42101", @"5394 Brownsville Road Brownsville, KY 42210", @"945 Perrytown Road  Scottsville, KY 42164", @"2033 Thomerson Park Road Austin, KY 42123", @"5824 S. Jackson Hwy. Horse Cave, KY 42749", @"125 Kennedy Road Guston, KY   40142", @"1869 Wooden Lane Elizabethtown, KY 42701", @"1918 Bardstown Road Hodgenville, KY 42748", @"8631 Campbellsville Road Hodgenville, KY 42748", @"1380 Frogg Lane Raywick, KY 40060", @"2212 Saloma Road Campbellsville, KY 42718", @"313 Hwy 1464 Greensburg, KY 42743", @"230 Heavenly Lane Columbia, KY 42728", @"1842 N. Main St. Jamestown, KY 42629", @"500 Cedar Hill Road Albany, KY 42602", @"8350 West 80 Nancy, KY 42544-8756", @"3917 N. Hwy 837 Science Hill, KY 42553", @"755 Elihu Rush Branch Road Somerset, KY 42501", @"6550 Cumberland Falls Road Corbin, KY 40701", @"735 Latham Road Somerset, KY 42503", @"Hwy 461, at 3 mile marker Somerset, KY 42503", @"1300 Plato-Vanhook Road Somerset, KY 42503", @"35 Skyline Drive Eubank, KY 42567", @"169 Pine Hill Road Paint Lick, KY 40461", @"230 N. Main St. Berea, KY 40404", @"2285 Barnes Mill Road Richmond, KY 40475", @"1113 Tates Creek Road Richmond, KY 40475", @"686 Buckeye Road Lancaster, KY 40444", @"471 Stanford Avenue Danville, KY 40422-1927", @"623 Talmage-Mayo Road Harrodsburg, KY 40330", @"4189 Craintown Rd. Gravel Switch, KY 40328", @"1805 Booker Road Springfield, KY 40069", @"2645 Bardstown Road Springfield, KY 40061", @"9430 Bloomfield Road Bloomfield, KY 40008", @"460 Buffalo Run Road Shepherdsville, KY 40165", @"4877 Hwy 44E Shepherdsville, KY 40165", @"6516 Echo Trail Jeffersontown, KY 40299", @"5613 Cooper Chapel Road Louisville, KY 40229", @"2400 Lower Hunters Trace Louisville, KY 40216", @"9120 Blowing Tree Road Louisville, KY 40220", @"12523 Taylorsville Road Jeffersontown, KY 40299", @"1029 Vigo Road Shelbyville, KY 40065", @"6805 Castle Hwy. Pleasureville, KY 40057", @"1330 Mulberry Pike Shelbyville, KY 40065", @"985 Vance Road Turners Station, KY 40075", @"215 Parker Drive LaGrange, KY 40031", @"2580 Hwy 42 W. Bedford, KY 40006", @"3721 Hwy 421 N Bedford, KY 40006", @"1660 Highway 421 N Bedford, KY 40006", @"3690 East-West Connector (Rte 676) Frankfort, KY 40601", @"2287 Long Lick Road Georgetown, KY 40324", @"525 Wilson Lane Owenton, KY 40359", @"4275 Hwy 1316 Sparta, KY 41086", @"130 McClelland Circle Georgetown, KY 40324", @"877 Cincinnati Road Georgetown, KY 40324", @"2165 Sherman Mount Zion Rd. Dry Ridge, KY 41035", @"8707 Camp Ernst Road Union, KY 41091", @"7812 East Bend Road Burlington, KY 41005", @"12449 Decoursey Pike Morning View, KY 41063", @"3246 Augusta-Berlin Road Brooksville, KY 41004", @"5350 Raymond Road May's Lick, KY 41055", @"4085 Ewing Road Ewing, KY 41039", @"1069 Ruddles Mill Road Paris, KY 40361", @"239 Lail Lane Paris, KY 40361", @"180 Stone Road Georgetown, KY 40324", @"2231 Houston Antioch Road Lexington, KY 40516", @"1801 Alexandria Drive Lexington, KY 40504", @"1396 Pinckard Pike Versailles, KY 40383", @"1371 Beverly Lane Nicholasville, KY 40356", @"4776 Old Boonesboro Road Winchester, KY 40391", @"3925 Old Boonesboro Road Winchester, KY 40391", @"11620 Main Street Jeffersonville, KY 40337", @"2726 Osborne Road Mt. Sterling, KY 40353", @"99 Union Road Beattyville, KY 41311", @"1523 Hwy 119 North Whitesburg, KY 41815", @"52 KY Route 3224 River, KY 41254", @"2836 State Route 1 Greenup, KY 41144", @"45 Katherine Lane Greenup, KY 41144", @"1483 Big Run Road Wallingford, KY 41093", @"430 Wallacetown Road Paint Lick, KY 40461", @"9730 KY 136W Calhoun, KY 42327", @"4818 Hwy 144 Owensboro, KY 42303", @"88 Noe Lane Russellville, KY 42276", @"59 Williams Cemetery Rd. Hodgenville, KY 42748", @"1114 KY Hwy 829 Albany, KY 42602", @"680 Dug Hill Rd. Elk Horn, KY 42733", @"975 Frankfort Rd. Lawrenceburg, KY 40342", @"164 Old Peonia Loop Clarkson, KY 42726", nil];

    displayItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:title];

    searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [displayItems count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *marketListIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CellImage.png"];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:marketListIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:marketListIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FranklinGothicStd-ExtraCond" size:20.0];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FranklinGothicStd-ExtraCond" size:14.0];
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    cell.backgroundView = image;

    cell.textLabel.text = [displayItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [subtitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    DTCustomColoredAccessory *accessory = [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:cell.textLabel.textColor];
    accessory.highlightedColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    cell.accessoryView =accessory;

    return cell;
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if ([searchText length] == 0)
    {
        [displayItems removeAllObjects];
        [displayItems addObjectsFromArray:title];
    }
    else
    {
        [displayItems removeAllObjects];
        for (NSString *string in title)
        {
            NSRange r = [string rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if (r.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                [displayItems addObject:string];
            }
        }
    }
    [tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)aSearchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)aSearchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

EDIT:  I'm trying to use a dictionary now with keys for title and subtitle but the app is crashing when I open this view.

Here is how I'm creating the dictionary.

```
keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"titleKey", @"subtitleKey", nil];
    objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [objects addObject:title];
    [objects addObject:subtitle];

    marketDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    marketDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

    farmMarkets = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:marketDictionary, nil];

    displayItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:farmMarkets];
```

Here is how I'm trying to set the cell titles and subtitles.  The app crashes on this first line.

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[displayItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"titleKey"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[displayItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"subtitleKey"];
```

Here is the error in the log.

```
2013-06-19 15:16:16.240 KFBNewsroom[13461:c07] -[__NSArrayM isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12745290
2013-06-19 15:16:16.241 KFBNewsroom[13461:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12745290'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend storing your titles and subtitles together rather than separate arrays. You could use an array of dictionaries with @"title" and @"subtitle" keys or create a custom model object with these properties.

Either way, all you have to do is apply the same logic you are using with the title strings to the corresponding subtitle strings. Without changing your data structure you could update your `searchBar:textDidChange:` logic to look like this:

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [title count]; i++ )
{
    if ( ([[title objectAtIndex:i rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] != NSNotFound) || ([[subtitle objectAtIndex:i rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] != NSNotFound) ) {
        [displayItems addObject:string];
    }
}
```

This way `searchText` can be in either the title string or the subtitle string.

NOTE: I typed this without looking at the documentation or using Xcode's autocomplete, so there may very well be typos, misspellings, or syntax errors.

UPDATE:

Based on the information in your edit I believe the structure of your farmMarkets array is wrong. What you want is to have the farmMarkets array contain an NSDictionary for each market. Each individual dictionary then has the @"title" and @"subtitle" keys. To make this easier to visualize you may want to initialize farmMarkets like this:

```
NSArray *farmMarkets = @[
    @{@"title"      :    @"Cates Farm",
      @"subtitle"   :    @"Hwy 425 Henderson, KY 42420"},

    @{@"title"      :    @"Broadbent B & B Foods",
      @"subtitle"   :    @"257 Mary Blue Road Kuttawa, KY 42055"},

    @{@"title"      :    @"Cayce's Pumpkin Patch",
      @"subtitle"   :    @"153 Farmersville Road Princeton, KY 42445"}
];
```

(FYI, just as @"asdf" will create an NSString, @[list, of, objects] will create an NSArray and @{key : value, key : value} will create an NSDictionary.)

You can then do this to get the info for your cells:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[displayItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[displayItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"subtitle"];
```

Comment: I'm trying to make it work with a dictionary but having problems.  I've updated my original post with what I'm trying.

Comment: I believe you are getting `[__NSArrayM isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` is because your displayItems array contains a single item which is the marketDictionary. I will update my answer with more details because I don't think I can format code in a comment.

Comment: Considering how many items I would need to put in, is there a faster way than just putting them in individually?

Comment: You could save them in as XML or some other format and then write logic to parse this file and create the array of dictionaries. How do you have this data stored right now and how many items are there?

Comment: There are about 102 titles and 102 subtitles.  I just had them in the title and subtitle arrays.

Comment: I see. I took another look at your original code and saw how you were declaring those arrays. If you want to preserve what you have you could loop through the items in these arrays like so `for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [title count]; i++ ) { [farmMarkets addObject:@{ @"title" : [title objectAtIndex:i], @"subtitle" : [subtitle objectAtIndex:i]}; }`  I would recommend reformatting your data though, even if this means simply using text manipulation to lay it out the way I did above. Updating your arrays will be a huge pain in the future.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that. Now the only issue I have is getting the search to work like I want it.  I may be back but for now, thanks for the help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32075/discussion-between-user2029585-and-alex)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having two arrays, you should create an array of dictionaries.

When searching for the title you find the match you should put that dictionary to resultant array. Now using the array of dictionary you can retrieve the subtitle associated with title.

you can also do below change in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [displayItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
int currentIndex = [title indexOfObject:cell.textLabel.text];   
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [subtitle objectAtIndex:currentIndex];
```